# How do you run example code snippets with html output from gae?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

[The following code comes from here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/responseclass) How am I supposed to see the results? Can I use the GAE interactive console somehow, or do I need to create a whole app with an app.yaml etc and run it in the gae launcher? I am particularly interested in snippets with html.

```
import datetime

from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("<html><body>")
        self.response.out.write("<p>Welcome to the Internet!</p>")
        self.response.out.write("</body></html>")

        expires_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(365)
        expires_str = expires_date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
        self.response.headers.add_header("Expires", expires_str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to run it in the development server. You see the results in your browser.

Comment: Ok, I did as you suggested. Now can you tell me what the last line in the example code does because I don't see it in the html output(`self.response.headers.add_header("Expires", expires_str)`)?

Comment: Seems to be adding an `Expires` header to the HTTP response to tell the browser how long to cache it for.

Comment: I assumed anything like that would have to show in the raw page output, but all I see is the following. `<html><body><p>Welcome to the Internet!</p></body></html>` A puzzle to me.

Comment: Get chrome and press Crtl shift and i and you will get a console that will allow you to inspect the header s of that page, which is where the info is, not in the web page itself. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview#access

Comment: Paul, Thanks for that link etc. On my Mac I use Cmd Option I (and btw, Cmd Shift I seems to create an email message of the html page). I still cannot locate that Expires header business in the developer console. But there is such a wealth of info there. I guess I need to find a video or some docs to use those developer tools better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the development appserver?